# Javascript If-else

Tags: javascript

Attempting to do my first bit of Javascript if / else. Basically I would like to display DIVs according to the number selected from the Radio box field. If option 3 is selected, I would like div 1, 2 and 3 to be visible. 
I am clearly going wrong somewhere. 
Thoughts / help is very much appreciated.

```
<script type="text/javascript" >

$(document).ready(function() {

$("input[name$='supplier']").click(function() {

var test = $(this).val();

if (test=1)
{
$("div.hidesupplier").hide();
$("#suppliersourced1").show();
}

else if (test=2)
{
$("div.hidesupplier").hide();
$("#suppliersourced1").show();
$("#suppliersourced2").show();
}

else if (test==3)
{
$("#suppliersourced1").show();
$("#suppliersourced2").show();
$("#suppliersourced3").show();
}

});
});
</script>

Number of Suppliers:
<label><input name="supplier" type="radio" value="1">1.</label> 
<label><input name="supplier" type="radio" value="2">2.</label>
<label><input name="supplier" type="radio" value="3">3.</label>

<div id="suppliersourced1" class="CF hidesupplier" style="display: none;">Supplier One</div>
<div id="suppliersourced2" class="CF hidesupplier" style="display: none;">Supplier Two</div>
<div id="suppliersourced3" class="CF hidesupplier" style="display: none;">Supplier Three</div>
```

Comment: If you're going to check the same variable against different values, `switch/case` would be better than `if/then/elseif`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have = instead of == in your first 2 conditions.

Comment: Argh! So simple and I am so dumb! Thanks heaps. Was staring at it for around 20 minutes trying to figure out what I was doing wrong!

Comment: Everyone does it at least once.

My "Argh!" moments are 

    if(condition); 
        do something...

Answer (score 5):

A cleaner and faster version would be:

```
$("input[name$='supplier']").click(function() {
    var test = $(this).val();
    $("div.hidesupplier").each(function() {

        // get the id of the current supplier, eg: "suppliersourced1"   
        var myID = $(this).attr('id');

        // get the last character and convert it to a number
        myID = parseInt(myID.substring(myID.length()-1, 1), 10);

        // show all with id less than or eq to test 
        // hide all with id more than test
        if(myID <= test) $(this).show(); else $(this).hide();
    });
});
```

*Cleaner* because you have almost no repeating code. *Faster* because you dont blindly hide everything and show specific elements, but only hide and show appropriate elements in one go. *Faster* also because there is lesser bytes of JS code to be transferred, parsed and executed.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Definitely kind of makes sense. Just learning JS right now so I am sure it will dawn on me shortly. I cannot however manage to make the solution above work. Sure I will figure it out though. Thanks again.