# Javascript if and else if statements

Tags: javascript

```
if (isNaN(food)){
    isRunning = false;
    break;
    }

if (food === 'apple') {

    size='1 small (4 oz.)'; 
    calories='80 kcl';

}else if (food ==='banana') {

    size='1 medium (6 oz.)'; 
    calories='101 kcl';
}else if (food ==='grape') {

    size='each'; 
    calories='2 kcl';
}
```

Anyone spot the mistake of this loop?
Thanks for the people who answered my enquries

Comment: `=` is assignment, not comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript If-else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14640601/javascript-if-else)

Comment: You should not change the content of your question after it was already answered. Instead, create a new question. As it is now, my answer regarding comparison operator is no longer valid, since you changed it in your code.

Comment: The mistake in your new/modified code is quite obvious, but I will not answer it here. Please create a new question instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`food = 'apple'` assigns the value `apple` to the variable `food`. What you want to use for comparison, is the `==` operator, which compares `food` and `'apple'`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the if condition expression with “==“ i.e comparison operator instead of “=“ i.e. assignment operator.